# Checking multiple checkboxes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a problem when trying to use check boxes for a string field.

Basically, what I need to do is have a field in my table, named category for example, and have checkboxes to pass values to it.

The problem I am encountering with that is that if I click more than one box, it only saves the value of the last clicked.

My _form code:

<%= f.check_box :category, "Category1", nil %> <%= f.label :"Category 1" %>
<%= f.check_box :category, "Category2", nil %> <%= f.label :"Category 2" %>
<%= f.check_box :category, "Category3", nil %> <%= f.label :"Category 3" %>

After some research, i found out that adding ":multiple => true" would solve it, but the only thing is does is not give a value at all.
Is there anyone able to help me? Thank you for your time:)

Comment: Can you share the server log generated upon submitting the form. Also, share `create` action of the controller. What is the field type of `Category` attribute.

Comment: I believe if you inspect your source code in the DOM you will see that it is generating something like `<input type="checkbox" name="category[Category1]" />`. You can also remove the nil as the third argument it is by default a empty hash.

Comment: Not sure how to see the server log but here are the rest:
def create
  products = Product.new(product_params)
  if products.save
     redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product successfully added."
  else
     render action: 'new'
  end
end

And the category attribute is a string (t.string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize the `category` attribute while saving in the database. Add the following line in your `model`:

```
    serialize :category, Array
```

Also, if you are using `Rails 4` then in controller class permit `category` as an array wherever you are permitting parameters.

```
params.require(:modelname).permit(:attr1, :attr2, :category => [])
```

Comment: Hi, would you serialize every attribute that can be a "0, 1, or many" such as this? Maybe he can have an associated table or something

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. One question though, as it is now, when I check a box and go to the /show page, the values of the category field are displayed like this(let's say i picked cat1 and 2): ["category1","category3"]. Is there a way to make it into something like: category1, category3 ?

Comment: Glad to help :). Display it as <%= objectname.category.join(", ") %>

Comment: That seems to only work in my /show page for some reason. If I add that to my index page inside the table that displays all products, I get this "error undefined method `join' for "Category1":String">.
Sorry if it's a silly question, but I just started using rails and I am a bit lost ^^

Comment: It might be because there are existing records in the table which were not inserted as serialized Array. Delete and recreate those records and try again.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly the problem. Thank you very much for your help!:)

Answer (score 0):

try this

controller

```
@categories = Category.all
```

view

```
<%@categories.each do |cat|%>
<%= check_box_tag "categories[]", cat.name %>
<% end %>
```

or `cat.id`